# KStreams application - state.dir - No .checkpoint file

Tags: docker, apache-kafka-streams, rocksdb

I have a KStreams application running inside a Docker container which uses a persistent key-value store. My runtime environment is Docker 1.13.1 on RHEL 7.

I have configured `state.dir` with a value of `/tmp/kafka-streams` (which is the default).

When I start this container using "docker run", I mount `/tmp/kafka-streams` to a directory on my host machine which is, say for example, `/mnt/storage/kafka-streams`.

My `application.id` is "myapp". I have 288 partitions in my input topic which means my state store / changelog topic will also have that many partitions. Accordingly, when start my Docker container, I see that there a folder with the number of the partition such as 0_1, 0_2....0_288 under `/mnt/storage/kafka-streams/myapp/`

When I shutdown my application, I do not see any `.checkpoint` file in any of the partition directories.

And when I restart my application, it starts fetching the records from the changelog topic rather than reading from local disk. I suspect this is because there is no `.checkpoint` file in any of the partition directories. (Note : I can see the `.lock` and `rocksdb` sub-directory inside the partition directories)

This is what I see in the startup log. It seems to be bootstrapping the entire state store from the changelog topic i.e. performing network I/O rather than reading from what is on disk :

```
2022-05-31T12:08:02.791 [mtx-caf-f6900c0a-50ca-43a0-8a4b-95eaad9e5093-StreamThread-122] WARN  o.a.k.s.p.i.ProcessorStateManager - MSG=stream-thread [myapp-f6900c0a-50ca-43a0-8a4b-95eaa
d9e5093-StreamThread-122] task [0_170] State store MyAppRecordStore did not find checkpoint offsets while stores are not empty, since under EOS it has the risk of getting uncommitte
d data in stores we have to treat it as a task corruption error and wipe out the local state of task 0_170 before re-bootstrapping
2022-05-31T12:08:02.791 [myapp-f6900c0a-50ca-43a0-8a4b-95eaad9e5093-StreamThread-122] WARN  o.a.k.s.p.internals.StreamThread - MSG=stream-thread [mtx-caf-f6900c0a-50ca-43a0-8a4b-95eaad
9e5093-StreamThread-122] Detected the states of tasks [0_170] are corrupted. Will close the task as dirty and re-create and bootstrap from scratch.
org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.TaskCorruptedException: Tasks [0_170] are corrupted and hence needs to be re-initialized
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorStateManager.initializeStoreOffsetsFromCheckpoint(ProcessorStateManager.java:254)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StateManagerUtil.registerStateStores(StateManagerUtil.java:109)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.initializeIfNeeded(StreamTask.java:216)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.tryToCompleteRestoration(TaskManager.java:433)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.initializeAndRestorePhase(StreamThread.java:849)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:731)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:583)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:556)
```

1. Should I expect to see a `.checkpoint` file in each of the partition directories under /mnt/storage/kafka-streams/myapp/ when I shutdown my application ?
2. Is this an issue because I am running my KStreams app inside a docker container ? If there were permissions issues, then I would have expected to see issues in creating the other files such as .lock or rocksdb folder (and it's contents).
3. If I run this application as a standalone/runnable Springboot JAR on my Windows laptop i.e. not in a Docker container, I can see that it creates the .checkpoint file as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you've configured the `ENTRYPOINT` in your `DockerFile` to a script, right?

Something like:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/run.sh"]
```

And in that script you'll be invoking java:

```
#!/bin/bash

java <cp, and thing to run>
```

If this is the case, then TERM signals will NOT be forwarded to your Java process.  You need to use [exec](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html#SHELL_BUILTIN_COMMANDS):

```
#!/bin/bash

exec java <cp, and thing to run>
```

With `exec`, TERM signals will be forwarded.

Why?

The reason your Java process is NOT getting TERM signals is that Docker is sending the TERM signal to the `ENTRYPOINT`, i.e. the shell process running your script, and the script is not forwarding this on to your Java Process.

The `exec` command *replaces* the shell process with your Java process, so TERM signals are now sent to it.

Answer (score 0):

My java application inside the Docker container is run via an entrypoint script. It seems that if I stop the container, then it does not send the TERM signal to my java process and hence does not have a clean shutdown of the java KStreams application.

So, all I needed to do was to find a way to somehow send a TERM signal to my java application inside the container.

For the moment, I just ssh'ed into the container and did a `kill -s TERM <pid>` for my java process.
Once I did that, it resulted in a clean shutdown and thus created the `.checpoint` file as well.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Do you find any solution?